# Javascript produce this simple array of numbers from simple data

Tags: javascript, arrays

If anyone can think of a better title I'm open to it. Anyway I've been struggling to get this to produce just the right output for several hours now but haven't got it to work in all situations.

> Simply put I have a list of fixed dates including every day between a range, and I need to produce an array of the *gaps* between the dates that are missing in the provided date array.

So in the example below:

```
fixed dates: [2019-09-23, 2019-09-24, 2019-09-25, 2019-09-26, 2019-09-27, 2019-09-28, 2019-09-29]
given dates: [2019-09-23, 2019-09-24, 2019-09-26, 2019-09-27, 2019-09-28]
```

The first number is 0 since there is no gap between the opening date and the provided date. Then from there it is just the gaps between each date:
`[0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]`

To make it a little clearer how we get these numbers:

```
 [2019-09-23, 2019-09-24, 2019-09-25, 2019-09-26, 2019-09-27, 2019-09-28, 2019-09-29]
 [2019-09-23, 2019-09-24,             2019-09-26, 2019-09-27, 2019-09-28]
0       1         2                         1          1           2
```

I got this to work ok after a while but there is one other factor, there is data associated with each date and if there are two or more the same in a row, we also skip a day. Note that the data and given dates have the same length and thus the same indices. So with two values in a row in the example below, we skip that as well so the desired output would be as follows:

```
fixed dates: [2019-09-23, 2019-09-24, 2019-09-25, 2019-09-26, 2019-09-27, 2019-09-28, 2019-09-29]
given dates: [2019-09-23, 2019-09-24, 2019-09-26, 2019-09-27, 2019-09-28]
given data: [82.0, 85.5, 85.5, 85.0, 86.5]
desired output: [0, 1, 3, 1*, 1, 2]
```

- skipped
  Must skip otherwise there will be too many elements in the list.

I won't post what I tried since I don't think it is that great and moreover will influence the answers. But I tried anything from finding the difference between the dates, to using a simple increment in a for loop which increases each time a date is skipped.

If there is a difference between the initial fixed date and the first given date then the first number in the array will not be zero, it will be the difference.

Here is some data and the desired outputs:

```
fixed dates: [2019-09-23, 2019-09-24, 2019-09-25, 2019-09-26, 2019-09-27, 2019-09-28, 2019-09-29, 2019-09-30, 2019-10-01, 2019-10-02, 2019-10-03, 2019-10-04]
given dates: [2019-09-23, 2019-09-24, 2019-09-26, 2019-09-27, 2019-09-28, 2019-10-01]
given data: [82.0, 85.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.5, 84.0]
desired output: [0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3]

fixed dates: [2019-09-09, 2019-09-10, 2019-09-11, 2019-09-12, 2019-09-13, 2019-09-14, 2019-09-15, 2019-09-16, 2019-09-17, 2019-09-18]
given dates: [2019-09-10, 2019-09-11, 2019-09-12, 2019-09-13, 2019-09-15, 2019-09-17]
given data: [85.0, 81.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 85.5]
desired output: [1, 1, 1, 3, 2*, 2, 2]
* skipped
Must skip otherwise there will be too many elements.

fixed dates: [2019-09-09, 2019-09-10, 2019-09-11, 2019-09-12, 2019-09-13, 2019-09-14, 2019-09-15, 2019-09-16, 2019-09-17, 2019-09-18, 2019-09-19, 2019-09-20, 2019-09-21, 2019-09-22]
given dates: [2019-09-10, 2019-09-11, 2019-09-12, 2019-09-13, 2019-09-15, 2019-09-17, 2019-09-18, 2019-09-19, 2019-09-20, 2019-09-21]
given data: [85.0, 81.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 85.5, 85.0, 86.0, 85.0, 84.5]
desired output: [1, 1, 1, 3, 2*, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
* skipped
Must skip otherwise there will be too many elements.

fixed dates: [2019-09-09, 2019-09-10, 2019-09-11, 2019-09-12, 2019-09-13, 2019-09-14, 2019-09-15, 2019-09-16, 2019-09-17, 2019-09-18, 2019-09-19, 2019-09-20, 2019-09-21, 2019-09-22]
given dates: [2019-09-10, 2019-09-11, 2019-09-12, 2019-09-13, 2019-09-15, 2019-09-16, 2019-09-17, 2019-09-18, 2019-09-19, 2019-09-20, 2019-09-21]
given data: [85.0, 81.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 83.5, 85.5, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 84.5]
desired output: [1, 1, 1, 3, 2*, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2*, 1*, 2]
* skipped
Must skip otherwise there will be too many elements.
```

I guess it may be a bit too difficult but I thought I'd post it anyway and see if someone can come up with a nice solution.

Comment: could you develop how you get your array ```[0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]``` ? that is (at least the 1 and 2 which follow 0)

Comment: @user753642 Not sure what you mean...the question is how to get that array from the data provided. That's why it says `desired output` next to it.

Comment: you are explaining that this array should contain the gaps between the provided dates... but do you know its logic generation (if yes, why should it be a 1 in desired output given input data) or are you asking us to reverse engineer the function which maps the input to desired output? (that they given to you or something)

Comment: @user753642 1 represents a single day, if there is a 2 day gap like in the first example `2019-09-24, 2019-09-26` we get a 2. The zero at the beginning is a special case just for the beginning which is the gap between the first fixed date and the first given date, which in the first example there is no gap so it's 0.

Comment: @user753642 Added another example near the beginning of my question to show the date gaps a little more clearly.

Comment: you were clear. (I have not figured out the logic for the last element but i guess it is a detail). Regarding data, if two elements in a row are the same, say at index ```i``` and ```j```, which day has to be skipped? (I assume the ```*``` refers to the _additional_ day which has to be skipped). In example ```[82.0, 85.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.5, 84.0]```, ```85``` is the same at idx ```1``` and ```3```, but you don't seem to be skipping anything? In ```[85.0, 81.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 85.5, 85.0, 86.0, 85.0, 84.5]``` 85 occurs at idx ```0,2,3,6,8``` but you apparently skip a day at the 4th idx. why?

Comment: @user753642 We only skip them if they are consecutive. Sorry it's pretty weird, that's why I hesitated posting it.

Comment: @user753642 So basically if we have 24th, 26th we need two days for the gap. If the data on these days is 86, 86 and 86 again for the 27th, then we're gonna get 3, starting from the 24th. So we're extending the length from the leftmost entry and the 3 represents all three entries from the 24th to the 27th.

Comment: I think your examples are inconsistents.
in ```[82.0, 85.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.5, 84.0]``` len(data)=6 and len(output)=7.
but in ```[85.0, 81.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 85.5]``` len(data)=6 and len(output)=6 too!!
in ```[85.0, 81.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 85.5, 85.0, 86.0, 85.0, 84.5]``` the increments (by ignoring data and first and last elem) are:
```1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1``` but by taking a +1 from data, we can't reach 3,2,2.
Finally, the main problem is that you have not simplified the problem: date can be simplified as numbers. problem lies not in begin end so strip them out as well

Comment: @user753642 You're right about the length of one example, it should have an extra 1 at the beginning. But for `1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1` we have to reach `3,2*,2` because the middle 2 is skipped.

Comment: I can't figure out what the skip action does. Sometimes it operates at previous idx sometimes it adds more than one day to the sum of gaps, maybe an explanation of one of your example would help (at least me) (instead of just input/output)

Comment: I wonder why in the second example from your last code block it has four times 1 at the start of the output. It is as if you don't group the two values of 85.0 together. Should the output not be [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2] instead of [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2]?

Comment: Also, in the first example of that last code block: shouldn't the last number in the output be 4 instead of 3? So [0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4] instead of [0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3]?

Comment: @trincot For `[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2]` it does not start from the first date so the first number is 1 instead of 0. It was originally as you say but user753642 pointed out that it was wrong so I added the extra 1.

Comment: @user753642 It can add more than one to the gap if for example the dates are 24th and 26th and the values are both 85.0, then it will be 2 + 2 = 4 for the 24th and then the 26th will be skipped.

Comment: I think you misread my comments? I do not ask about the initial 0. I do understand that a 1 is needed for the difference in start dates, but even if I count that step 1, I don't see why there should be four of them. The 3 should kick in with the first value of 85.0. Could you also look at my second comment?

Comment: @trincot Yes you're right actually. When I corrected it I should have added a 2 to the end, and not a 1 to the beginning. I've corrected my answer. It should be `[1, 1, 1, 3, 2*, 2, 2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of extending gaps when values remain unchanged, and accounting for the dates for which there is no data, I would suggest iterating over the fixed data in reverse order.

I provide here an implementation in JavaScript.

```js
function getGaps(fixedDates, dates, values) {
    let j = dates.length-1;
    let result = Array(dates.length+1).fill(0);
    let gap = 0;
    for (let i = fixedDates.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // Go backwards
        gap++; // Count every entry in fixedDates 
        if (j >= 0 && fixedDates[i] === dates[j]) {
            result[j + 1] = gap;
            // Only reset gap when value is different from previous
            if (j === 0 || values[j] !== values[j - 1]) gap = 0; 
            j--;
        }
    }
    result[0] = gap;
    return result;
}

let tests = [[
    ["2019-09-23", "2019-09-24", "2019-09-25", "2019-09-26", "2019-09-27", "2019-09-28", "2019-09-29"],
    ["2019-09-23", "2019-09-24", "2019-09-26", "2019-09-27", "2019-09-28"],
    [82.0, 85.5, 85.5, 85.0, 86.5]
], [
    ["2019-09-23", "2019-09-24", "2019-09-25", "2019-09-26", "2019-09-27", "2019-09-28", "2019-09-29", "2019-09-30", "2019-10-01", "2019-10-02", "2019-10-03", "2019-10-04"],
    ["2019-09-23", "2019-09-24", "2019-09-26", "2019-09-27", "2019-09-28", "2019-10-01"],
    [82.0, 85.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.5, 84.0]
], [
    ["2019-09-09", "2019-09-10", "2019-09-11", "2019-09-12", "2019-09-13", "2019-09-14", "2019-09-15", "2019-09-16", "2019-09-17", "2019-09-18"],
    ["2019-09-10", "2019-09-11", "2019-09-12", "2019-09-13", "2019-09-15", "2019-09-17"],
    [85.0, 81.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 85.5]
], [
    ["2019-09-09", "2019-09-10", "2019-09-11", "2019-09-12", "2019-09-13", "2019-09-14", "2019-09-15", "2019-09-16", "2019-09-17", "2019-09-18", "2019-09-19", "2019-09-20", "2019-09-21", "2019-09-22"],
    ["2019-09-10", "2019-09-11", "2019-09-12", "2019-09-13", "2019-09-15", "2019-09-17", "2019-09-18", "2019-09-19", "2019-09-20", "2019-09-21"],
    [85.0, 81.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 85.5, 85.0, 86.0, 85.0, 84.5]
], [
    ["2019-09-09", "2019-09-10", "2019-09-11", "2019-09-12", "2019-09-13", "2019-09-14", "2019-09-15", "2019-09-16", "2019-09-17", "2019-09-18", "2019-09-19", "2019-09-20", "2019-09-21", "2019-09-22"],
    ["2019-09-10", "2019-09-11", "2019-09-12", "2019-09-13", "2019-09-15", "2019-09-16", "2019-09-17", "2019-09-18", "2019-09-19", "2019-09-20", "2019-09-21"],
    [85.0, 81.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 83.5, 85.5, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 84.5]
], [
    ["2019-09-30", "2019-10-01", "2019-10-02", "2019-10-03", "2019-10-04", "2019-10-05", "2019-10-06"],
    ["2019-10-01", "2019-10-05", "2019-10-06"],
    [84.0, 85.5, 85.0],
]];

for (let test of tests) console.log(JSON.stringify(getGaps(...test)));
```

There are 6 test cases here. The one that you presented first in your question, and 4 other examples you listed all together, and an additional case you mentioned in comments below.

The output of the second case (first of your block of 4) is different in the final number, but it is my understanding it should be like this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201064/discussion-on-answer-by-trincot-javascript-produce-this-simple-array-of-numbers).